# How to loop on div when you click on a button

Tags: javascript, loops, tags, webserver

I am trying to loop through my div. So when I click the button it loops through all the div and sees if one of them have it's tag to true. If so it sends an alert to do maintenance. if it's false then it sends an alert telling there's no maintenance needed. Here's the javascript I have for now;

I have tried to loop in it by taking the value (true or false) of the class "AlertMaint" and then by selecting all the div called "AlertMaint" to loop in them to see if their value was actually true or false. Then the corresponding alert should pop up. When I click on the button nothing happens. I would like to know if I'm not selecting my classes correctly and way to make it work.

```js
function RechercheMaint() {
  let MaintRequis = document.getElementsByClassName("AlertMaint").value;
  let VerifSilo = document.querySelectorAll(".AlertMaint");
  for (let x = 0; x < VerifSilo.length; x++) {
    if (MaintRequis == true) {
      let SiloMaint = MaintRequis.innerText;
      alert("La maintenance du silo #" + SiloMaint + " est requise.");
    } else {
      alert("Vos silos n'ont pas besoin de maintenance. Bonne journée!");
    }
  }
}
let ElemRecherche = document.getElementsByName("BtnRdm");
ElemRecherche.onclick = RechercheMaint;
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="barcontainer">
    <div class="bar" name="Silo1" style="height:80%"><span class="AlertMaint" data-ix-tag="Alm_Maintenace_Silo1">Silo ~ 1</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="barcontainer">
    <div class="bar" name="Silo2" style="height:70%"><span class="AlertMaint" data-ix-tag="Alm_Maintenace_Silo2">Silo ~ 2</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="barcontainer">
    <div class="bar" name="Silo3" style="height:30%"><span class="AlertMaint" data-ix-tag="Alm_Maintenace_Silo3">Silo ~ 3</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="barcontainer">
    <div class="bar" name="Silo4" style="height:90%"><span class="AlertMaint" data-ix-tag="Alm_Maintenace_Silo4">Silo ~ 4</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="barcontainer">
    <div class="bar" name="Silo5" style="height:20%"><span class="AlertMaint" data-ix-tag="Alm_Maintenace_Silo5">Silo ~ 5</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="barcontainer">
    <div class="bar" name="Silo6" style="height:40%"><span class="AlertMaint" data-ix-tag="Alm_Maintenace_Silo6">Silo ~ 6</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="barcontainer">
    <div class="bar" name="Silo7" style="height:60%"><span class="AlertMaint" data-ix-tag="Alm_Maintenace_Silo7">Silo ~ 7</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="barcontainer">
    <div class="bar" name="Silo8" style="height:10%"><span class="AlertMaint" data-ix-tag="Alm_Maintenace_Silo8">Silo ~ 8</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="BtnMaint_Parent">
  <div><input type="button" class="BtnMaint_Enf" name="BtnRdm" value="Recherche de maintenance" style="text-align: center" ;></div>
</div>
```

Sorry if the french words get you confused. To make it easier the Tags (Ex: data-ix-tag="Alm_Maintenace_Silo1") are meant to give values that are in another app which is coded in c# on ix developer.

Comment: 'if one of them have it's tag to true' - what does that mean? There's nothing in any of those elements which could be coerced to a boolean.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The tags make references to an other interface which is a boolean. Once both codes communicate, I want to see which one need the maintenance.

Comment: this line `let MaintRequis = document.getElementsByClassName("AlertMaint").value;` doesn't make sense. What should `MaintRequis` be?

Comment: @ITgoldman `let MaintRequis = document.getElementsByClassName("AlertMaint").value;` is used to put the value of the span's class in a variable which is true or false. 
`<div class="barcontainer">
                <div class="bar" name="Silo1" style="height:80%"><span 
                  class="AlertMaint" data-ix-tag="Alm_Maintenace_Silo1">Silo ~ 1</span> 
                </div>
 </div>`
Here is where `AlertMaint` class is in a span in the HTML.